# Why does display: block; used on my span tag affect all the divs above it?

Tags: html, css

I am working on a google maps project and I am trying to get the address to display;block but when I do it affects everything around it and shifts in the surrounding divs making it look wrong.

This is the CSS that I am using:

`.store-address span {
    display: block;
}`

This is the HTML that I am using:

```
    <div class="stores-list-container">
        <div class="stores-list">
            <div class="store-container">
                <div class="store-address">
                    <span>9100 SE 42nd St</span>
                    <span>Mercer Island, WA 98040</span>
                </div>
                <div class="store-phone-number">555-555-5555</div>
                <div class="store-number-container">
                    <div class="store-number">
                            1
                    </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
    </div>
```

This image shows how everything is now shifted to left, and what I need is for the address portion to stay like it is but for the phone number and number "1" to still technically have the full width of the box.

[map project screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYH73.png)

Comment: block will take the space which you have given for the element,i.e if you have provided height and width property for the class then it uses that. it looks like you have given `height` property for the class.

Comment: I'm sorry your question and code don't make sense. You applied a css to only store-address, yet you want phone number to be? What? All texts are left aligned by default. The html of phone number doesn't match that of address. Do you want each line to have a different style? Is that why you have separate classes. SO MUCH is unclear

Comment: @SamwellTarly I'm honestly super surprised this post confused you so bad. It's pretty simple. Of course there's much more CSS to this whole thing but I focused on the part that is giving me trouble. When I call the span tag inside of the div with the class store-address it affects all the surrounding divs. I'm trying to avoid this and want it to only affect the span tag. 

If you look at the map screenshot you can see that the little bit of CSS that I listed is affecting the divs around it such as phone, the number, etc. and I don't want it to do that.

Hope that is more clear.

Comment: A span set as a block within a div behaves exactly as a div. Your issue is caused by much more than the single line of CSS you posted. A general rule in stackoverflow is that you should provide a simplified yet full working code. Anything that we can directly paste into an environment. Hence although your html is sufficient, your entire CSS is required to identify the issue. Rough expected screenshot with whatever scribbled on will also be helpful. That is how a good question is posted. And good questions get good answers in minutes.